# Why do we use the zero vector for computing eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

While computing the eigenvectors, we use the zero determinant. I know what it states for. However, I can't understand why we do need to have a zero vector, which is stated in the definition of eigenvectors. 
Is it because eigenvectors always stay on the same line, as a zero vector in this case does?

Comment: The fundamental definition of an eigenvector of the matrix $A$ is that it is a nonzero vector $\mathbf v$ such that $A\mathbf v=\lambda\mathbf v$ for some scalar $\lambda$. Where do you see a zero vector in this definition?

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you're asking, but the zero vector is trivially an element of any eigenspace of any linear transformation, because for any transformation $T$ and any scalar $\lambda$, $T\vec{0} = \lambda \vec{0} = \vec{0}$.

Comment: We don't need any "zero vector" to compute eigenvalues. Perhaps you mean that since $\;\lambda\;$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix $\;A\iff (\lambda I-A)\;$ is a *singular* matrix, then we must evaluate the determinant of the above matrix, equate it to zero and etc....

Comment: I am asking about the definition itself, why do we have a zero vector here: 0⃗ =0⃗ =0⃗  . As far as I was concerned, it allows us to scale this zero vector, right?

Comment: The zero vector is by definition _never_ an eigenvector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to know the origins of the equation
$$
(A-\lambda I)v = 0
$$
where $A$ is a matrix, $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

The fact of the matter is that this is a quite opaque expression. It has lost a lot of resemblance to the original intent because it has been heavily manipulated algebraically.

The actual equation you want to solve (i.e. find both $\lambda$ and $v$ which work) is
$$
Av = \lambda v
$$
That's what "$v$ is an eigenvector of $A$" means. This is the actual equation you must *understand* in order to work with eigenvectors and eigenvalues. However, when it comes to *finding* eigenvectors and eigenvalues, it's not the best one, as $\lambda$ and $v$ "interfere" with one another; you can't really solve for just one of them. We manipulate it to
$$
Av = \lambda v\\
Av - \lambda v = 0\\
(A - \lambda I)v = 0
$$
(where that $I$ pops out of "nowhere" in order for the subtraction to make sense). After this manipulation, we see that the matrix $(A-\lambda I)$ has a non-trivial kernel: $v$ is contained in it. And any matrix with non-trivial kernel must have zero determinant. This allows us to find $\lambda$ before we even start looking for $v$, which makes things simpler.

Comment: According to this =, the real question is: how our A should look like such that it only scales our v vector?

Comment: @MariaLavroskaya That's a fair question, but for most applications, you have it the wrong way. Usually we already know what $A$ is, and we wonder what $\lambda$ and $v$ might be.

Comment: I just want to understand the concept in essence. I didn't get what do you mean by:   is contained in it

Comment: "it" refers to the kernel: $v$ is contained in the kernel of the matrix $A-\lambda I$.

Comment: That is our zero vector, right?

Comment: @MariaLavrakova No, $0$ is our zero vector. The eigenvector $v$ is by definition _not_ zero.

Comment: The kernel is the set of vectors which *map* to the $0$ vector

Comment: I got your point, thank you.